# Strange Problem with JSON Parsing

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-services, json

I have webservice in which I use JSON Parsing.

I hosted it on Godaddy server (AP region) having Shared Windows Hosting. It worked fine.

I then hosted it on my client's Godaddy server (EU Region) having Shared Windows Hosting. There it started giving "ExceptionType":"System.TypeInitializationException`" error.

I am confused as to what could be wrong. Same code works on one server and fails on the other.

Can there some settings on the server that can be altered?

What should I do to diagonise the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Providing some code would allow other people to try to diagnose the problem. At present, there probably isn't enough information to do so.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON Error when trying to fetch data in iPhone App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578548/json-error-when-trying-to-fetch-data-in-iphone-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got solution to this. Initally I was using Newton JSON 2.0 DLL. I changed it to Newton JSON 3.0 DLL and it started working fine.

Hope this helps someone having similar issue.